# Reducing the complexity of my Java program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, fractions

I have written a program in Java but it has a huge computational time, I don't know why. Can some one please give some pointers to reduce the complexity? Also after computing some values like after 3,100 it gives nullpointer exception.
Code:

```
public class Fraction
{
    long n;
    long d;

    public Fraction()
    {
        n= 0L;
        d= 1L;
    }

    public Fraction(long a,long b)
    {
        n= a;
        d= b;
    }

    public Fraction mult(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
        Fraction product = new Fraction();
        product.n = a.n * b.n;
        product.d = a.d * b.d;
        long hcf=gcd(product.n,product.d);
        product.n/=hcf;
        product.d/=hcf;
        return product;
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
        Fraction sum = new Fraction();
        sum.d = a.d * b.d;
        sum.n = a.n * b.d + a.d * b.n;
        long hcf=gcd(sum.n,sum.d);
        sum.n/=hcf;
        sum.d/=hcf;
        return sum;
    }

    public Fraction divide(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
        Fraction quotient = new Fraction();
        quotient.n = a.n * b.d;
        quotient.d = a.d * b.n;
        long hcf=gcd(quotient.n,quotient.d);
        quotient.n/=hcf;
        quotient.d/=hcf;
        return quotient;
    }

    long gcd(long a,long b)
    {
        long hcf=0,min;
        min=(a<b)?a:b;
        for(long i=1;i<=min;i++)
        {
        if(a%i==0 &&b%i==0)
        hcf=i;
        }
        return hcf;
    }
}

class foo extends Fraction
{
    static void main()
    {
        Fraction obj=new Fraction();
        Fraction f[][]=new Fraction[103][103];
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            f[1][i]=new Fraction(1L,(long)i);
            f[i][1]=f[1][i];
            f[2][i]=obj.add(new Fraction(1L,(2L*i)),new Fraction((i*i-1L),3L)); 
            f[i][2]=f[2][i];
        }
        for(int i=3;i<=100;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=100;j++)
            {
                f[i][j+1]=obj.divide(obj.add(new Fraction(1,1),obj.mult(f[i-1][j+1],f[i][j])), f[i-1][j]);
                System.out.println(i+","+j+"="+f[i][j].n+"/"+f[i][j].d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code in a readable way (just copy/paste your formatted code, select it all and click the {} button) and post the NPE stacktrace.

Comment: one improvement would be to use another algorithm to calculate the gcd (E.g. euclid's algorithm) which is much faster than the current search you're making.

Comment: `for(int j=1;j<=100;j++)  { f[i][j+1]=` j';s max value is 100, so j+1 == 101 => boom?

Comment: Also, there is no valid reason for your class `foo`, which is just the main class of your application, to `extend Fraction`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: you go to j+1, in the for clause you go until 100, so, you can obtain an index out of range exception.

Comment: Actually that was a mistake while typing here. I have changed array length to [103][103]. But can you please tell me why it shows nullpointer exception after printing 3,100. Also why, on the first hand, it is taking such a long time since the code isn't very complicated. Is it simply space complexity?

Answer (score 0):

The NPE comes from `j+1` and could have come from f[1][i]=new Fraction(...); where i skips 0 and some.
The slowness stems certainly also from gcd, see @wxyz.
`Fraction obj` could be called `final Fraction ZERO`.

Indexing convention is using `<` instead of `<=`: `for ...; i < f.length; ...`.

Either change

```
public Fraction divide(Fraction a, Fraction b)
```

into

```
public static Fraction divide(Fraction a, Fraction b)
```

where a call would be Fraction.divide(a, b).

or better

```
public Fraction divide(Fraction b)
```

where `this` takes the role of a.